# how to use bedtools extracts dna sequence position and length

Tags: sequence, bed, bedtools

Now I using bedtools and bed file to extracts dna sequence,
The code I run:

```
    bedtools getfasta -fi $ref -bed wt_1.bed


    # wt_1.bed" is chr1 4526760 4526761
```

it should represent 2 bases, not 1, isn't it? But I got 1 bases finally. If it's one, it's 4526760 or 4526761 base corresponding to？It's related to bed format about 0-based or getfasta? Thanks!

also like

```
# 0-6,but just gave five bases
>chr1:117223140-117223856
GTGGG
```

I searched around on Internet and hope to figure it out